# Is it possible to use AHK to open a specific tab in Firefox/Chrome for greater than 9 tabs

Tags: autohotkey

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
^a::Send, ^2
```

It works but only for less than 10 tabs.

I read about `winactivate` but apparently you would have to start typing the title of the web page (?).

I'd have to have it where I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and it takes me to tab 12, for example.

Comment: If you have more than one Super User account, they can be merged.  While we are always glad to help, you shouldn't utilize one account to suggest an edit for a question authored by the other account.

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.  For reference, the question was written under http://superuser.com/users/667354/hollyyyyyyyyyyyyyy and the account used for the edit was http://superuser.com/users/667346/user3411784

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it, but not directly.

You could also possibly look for an add-on that would give you extra navigation or jump-to flexibility for additional tabs.

To achieve a tab navigation indirectly you could jump to the last page with a shortcut and navigate to subsequent pages one at a time (except using the script of course).  Any inactive tabs (present but not loaded) would be activated and subsequently loaded in the process if they weren't already, but that wouldn't be the normal case for most users, and it would at least get you to the right tab.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe firefox.exe
^p::NavigateToTab(12)

NavigateToTab(TabNum) {
    ; For single digit jumps, just use the built-in shortcut
    If (TabNum>0 && TabNum<9) {
        SendInput ^%TabNum%
        Return
    }   

    ;Else...
    tabsOver := TabNum-8
    SendInput ^8        ; Go to 8th page since 9 jumps to end
    While (A_Index<=tabsOver) {
        Sleep 200           ; Slight delay for transitions, adjust as needed for good results
        SendInput ^{PgDn}
    }
    Return
}
```

The delay is just to help reliability in case there are keystroke processing delays by the browser.  It can be increased, decreased, or removed altogether if you achieve reliable operation with a different value... 200ms is just a starting value to try.